# How to share internet between two guest Win OS in VMware Workstation?

Tags: networking, vmware-workstation, sharing

I have VMware guest with Win 8.1 and USB stick with internet (mobile 3g)
How can I share internet with another VMware guest (WinXP)?

Specifically, I am running VMware Workstation 12.5 with 1st guest OS - Windows 8.1 + USB modem, 2nd guest OS - WinXP - with specific software (client-bank) which works only on XP. (I can't plugin USB modem to WinXP because it doesn't have USB 3.0. support, and I can't plugin modem to host, because I use it in intranet) I've made VM's to use same lan segment (via Settings-Network Adapter) and can ping one guest from another (both ways) Open question - how to share internet?

Comment: I have not tested this, but you possibly could [set up Internet Connection Sharing in the Windows guests](https://www.google.com/search?q=windows+internet+connection+sharing).

Comment: I try couple manuals on Internet Sharing, but don't get luck.
Here are screens of Guest2 Win8
http://imgur.com/a/Js2lb
Internet working fine, but doesn't shared with lan adapter Ethernet(0)